# JS animation Loop

Tags: javascript, animation

Firstly, I have looked at some similar questions which have already been answered but really don't understand JS and can't seem to get these methods to work.

I have this animation which moves an image from right to left over a duration of time. I would like the animation seem endless if possible. (meaning to loop or seem to continuously flow.) I'm animating clouds moving from right to left if that give you a better idea of what I'd like to achieve.

The Js looks like so:

```
var left = $('.layer-2').offset().left;

var scroll = -6000;

{
$(".layer-2").css({left:left}).animate({"left":scroll}, 99999);
}
```

I hope that is enough info? Thank you in advance for any help at all.

Comment: How so endless? Looping, or back-and forward? Or just stupidly slow?

Comment: @ironmike Animation endless means that the image will move by a very very very small offset, maybe `0.0000000000........0000001`  or something like that? it's very unclear, please clarify.

Comment: Opps... pretty badly worded... I mean to have it loop or continuously flow... Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest using CSS3 animations.  It supports endless looping and no knowledge of JS is required. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6289975/1015387

Comment: Thanks @njtman, I was going to use CSS3 animation but as far as I'm aware they're not supported with IE?

Answer (score 0):

In the times of flash, to do that, i used two equal images, when one was ending, the other was starting.

Here´s an example:

http://ap.companhiapropria.pt

(The buildings in the background)

Maybe you could try that with jquery?

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm looking to just loop the existing animation. Thanks though.